# Retrieve specific fields of all documents in mongodb collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a mongodb collection `user_col` that looks like this;

```
[{
  'Code': '557921',
  'Serial': 0,
  'UserName': 'morbidMacaw674005',
  '_id': ObjectId('5ee328c32cd209a5f60b56f1')},
 {
  'Code': '127142',
  'Serial': 1,
  'UserName': 'jumpyChough940073',
  '_id': ObjectId('5ee328c32cd209a5f60b56f2')},
 {
  'Code': '739173',
  'Serial': 2,
  'UserName': 'jumpyPretzels824773',
  '_id': ObjectId('5ee328c32cd209a5f60b56f3')},
]
```

I want to retrieve specific fields of all documents in a mongodb collection into a list of dictionaries. Here is my code;

```
list(user_col.find({"UserName": 1, "Code": 1}))
```

However, it returns nothing. What is wrong with my code?

If I run `list(user_col.find({}))`, all the documents are retrieved. I believe my code is quite close to getting it right.

I am using python 3.7, pymongo. I am also open to using mongoengine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

```
list(user_col.find({}, {"UserName": 1, "Code": 1}))
```

The first parameter `{}` was missing in the code in the question.